# Combine Azure Key Vault with Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am pretty new to Azure and I am trying to simulate a real production environment.
So, I've deployed a .netcore 3.1 app to an AppService resource. This web app is able to get the configuration from two other services - KeyVault and App Configuration. I already have configuraed the AppService identity.

1. I can get the keys from KeyVault using the following code:

   ```
   var settings = config.Build();
   var web = settings["KeyVault:Name"];
   var clientId = settings["KeyVault:ClientId"];
   var clientSecret = settings["KeyVault:ClientSecret"];

   config.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{web}.vault.azure.net/",
                           clientId,
                           clientSecret);
   ```
2. As I can get the keys from the App Configuration:

   ```
   var settings = config.Build();
   config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(settings["AppSettings:Endpoint"]);
   ```
3. And I am able to use them both at the same time through identities and AppConfiguration's key reference

   ```
   var settings = config.Build();
   config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
   {
       options
      .Connect(settings["AppSettings:Endpoint"])
      .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
      {
          kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
      });
   });
   ```

So, my question is about the code snippet #3: is it safe to store the `AppSettings:Endpoint` value the `appconfig.json` in a production environment? To be clear, I am referring to this value:

[image]

Moreover, I found [here](https://kasunkodagoda.com/2020/02/04/centralized-configuration-management-using-azure-app-configuration-using-azure-key-vault-side-by-side/) and explanation on how to use the two services together. But first of all, that solution doesn't work for me - I get an `Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: 'ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.'`.
On the second hand, he's not clear on where to store the `AppSettings:AppConfiguration:Endpoint` and `AppSettings:Identity:ClientId` values, it doesn't answer to my first question then.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - the endpoint https://[your_app_name].azconfig.io is safe to leave anywhere.  It does nothing without the other parts that make up the connection string.

Long answer - you can and probably should store the parts that are sensitive, connection strings and their parts, in Key  Vault as secrets.  If your code needs those values you have options on how to get the values to it.  Consider using the web config (it's equivalent as a place that would ordinarily have the secret values but put Key Vault references there instead.  Your way works also. Keep in mind that your way may require a code change if your config shifts away from what you've coded.

**Be sure that your access policy on KV is using the service principal of your app.**  *I repeat*, **be sure that your access policy on KV is using the service principal of your app.**  It will likely only need permissions "list" and "get" for secrets and NOTHING ELSE.

Do not store secrets in your web config or its equivalent.  Key Vault is almost free, it's so cheap.  I don't deploy apps without them getting their own vault as part of the solution.

Leave comments if this is unclear or needs web references.

Comment: The AppSettings:Endpoint key is referring to the ConnectionString highlighted into the screenshot, that is NOT equal to https://name.azconfig.io but it is like Endpoint=https://name.azconfig.io;Id=C...;Secret=9...
I changed my code in the following way to use both services:
`var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://name.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var a = client.GetSecret("AppSettings:Endpoint");
config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(a.Value);`
[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/key-vault-dotnet-core-quickstart/get-started-keyvault-net/)

Comment: To who's reading, the app must be deployed to Azure since it's using identities

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Azure Marange Identity to connect to APP Configuration. Use Azure.Identity preview version.

c# Example
https://github.com/nishanperera/Azure-App-Configuration-With-Key-Vault